# Passing arguments to a shell script

Tags: shell

I want to execute a shell script using `usage()` in the script.

I have to give three parameters in the usage block like below:

```
./script_name server_name path flag
```

How do I write the code block for this?

Finally, I need to read all the three parameters in a line to execute a jar file.

Comment: Currently, this question shows no effort of your own, only what you want somebody else to do for you - and that request is not very clear. You should [edit] it to add expected behaviour, sample input/output, the code you've written so far, and what specific problems you've encountered with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you pass parameters you can access them with $1, $2 ... $n and $@ to get everything at once.

```
./script_name server_name path flag
```

In the script code

```
echo $1, $2, $3
echo "$@" #will print the same thing
```

Comment: `echo $0` will print the command name, not the same thing. You might be confusing this with `awk`. With the shell printing all arguments is done with `$*` or better: `"$@"`

Comment: @KaranShah: I guess you mean `"$@"`, not `$@`.

Comment: You can accept the answer as correct and give a heads up then :)

Comment: @user1934428 What to do when someone answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers